# All of my Google AdWords accounts are suspended because I used the same credit card?

Tags: advertising, google-ads, cpc-ads

I do not understand why my account was suspended for "suspicious payment info".

1. The issue started when I set up my new campaign and added my billing information.  The campaign continued to have in red that I needed to add my billing information although I had already done so.
2. Two days later my account is suspended due to suspicious payment info.
       The address, billing information, name, 3 digit code and everything matches!  The credit card works and I had tested it.  NO 
   issues.
3. I am told to do an appeal form which I did.  However, within a day or so, I get a message from Google stating that the decision was final.

> Dear advertiser,
>
> Thanks for your continued patience during this
>   process. We’ve confirmed that your account is in violation of our
>   Google Ads policies. Since this decision is final, the account will
>   not be reinstated. Please avoid creating additional Google Ads
>   accounts, as they will be subjected to the same suspension. Our
>   support team will not be able to give you any more specifics on the
>   suspension. We appreciate your understanding and cooperation.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Elizabeth

So now how can I advertise on these websites?

Answer (score 3):

Only Google can say why your card was considered, "suspicious."

This is usually because they believe it is fraudulent in some manner (for instance, it's not your card). Although the support page is somewhat vague on the details, it clear that they only do it when they think you're breaking the law by using that payment method.

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2375414?hl=en-GB

This only affects you and that payment method, not the sites you wished to advertise. Someone else can still set up an Ads account to advertise your websites (although I would strongly recommend not attempting to use that payment method again).

You could create a new account to attempt this yourself, but if Google have told you not to and they catch you (and they will) you'll have those accounts shut down as well.

In future, if Google think your payment method is suspicious, it's usually best to simply replace it rather than argue with them.